# How to make flowing text extend and fit the div without specifying a height

Tags: css, html, text

I have structure where in the text needs to flow within the div box in the body. but seems like i cant get it to work. Maybe i am doing something wrong with the position: tag?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tf5Z8/

and this is what i was hoping to accomplish: http://oi58.tinypic.com/332njm9.jpg so that as text keeps getting added (less or more), it keeps the bottom intact and resizes the div accordingly. Right now i have the #bodyContainer set to height:300px;

```
#bodyContainer { width:1024px; height:300px; margin:auto; background-color:#f4f3e7; padding-top:20px;  }
```

but i don't want to do this since there would be many pages with different text amount.

Thanks a million, Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `#bodyContainer` `height` to `auto`. Like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tf5Z8/3/)

Comment: that worked ! Saw this tutorial: http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2012/02/this-css-layout-grid-is-no-holy-grail/ and you replied the very minute. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add `min-height`. So replace height property with min-height. And you are done.

Comment: When i add that tag to the CSS, it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Tf5Z8/1/ The golden background reduces. Whcih i dont want. I want want the #sidebarLeft and #sidebarRight to be nested within #bodyContainer, that when the text increses or reduces within #sidebarLeft and #sidebarRight the #bodyContainer would automatically adjust to the height.

Comment: UPDATE: Doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/Tf5Z8/2/ works perfectly. adding position:absolute; in the #bodyContainer tag, But since my site is positioned centered with margin:auto; the entire #bodyContainer block moves to the left edge of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any problems using absolute position try this method. Add `relative` position to `#bodyContainer` and `absolute` position to `#sidebarLeft`, then `float:right` `sidebarRight`. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/PuaLS/)

CSS changes

```
#bodyContainer { 
    width:1024px; 
    min-height:100px; 
    margin:auto; 
    background-color:#f4f3e7; 
    padding-top:20px; 
    position:relative; 
    overflow:hidden; 
}

#sidebarLeft { 
    height:100%; 
    width:360px; 
    background-color:#FFF; 
    margin-left:30px; 
    margin-bottom:20px; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:20px;
    left:0
}
#sidebarRight { 
    height:100%; 
    width:634px; 
    float:right; 
}
```

Comment: Great.. using this the height of the left sidebar will be the height of the body container. So even if the content in the right sidebar increases. the height of the left sider bar will be the same as the right side bar.