# Display whole div without scroll-bar - flexbox

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I am building a single-page website, and would like each section to have a minimum height of 100%.  While that works, if a div has more content than that the container div does not extend  to fit the content, leaving me with an ugly scroll bar.

**HTML**

```
<div id="general">
<div id="home">
<main> 
  <div class="main" id="home_main">
    <h1 id="head_home">/NAME GOES HERE</h1>
    <h3 id="tag_home">Funky tagline here</h3>
  </div> 
</main>
</div>
<div id="about">
<main> 
  <div class="main">
    <h1 id="head_about">About</h1>
<p id="para_about">Hide at bottom of staircase to trip human find something else more interesting paw at beetle and eat it before it gets away, rub whiskers on bare skin act innocent. Kitty loves pigs eat from dog's food missing until dinner time, and spend all night ensuring people don't sleep sleep all day or where is my slave? I'm getting</p>
</div> 
</main>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#general {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh !important;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -200;
}

#home {
  min-height: 100VH;
  background: yellow;
}

#about {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 40px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: visible;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle of my work so far: https://jsfiddle.net/chris2001/jqwqxL6n/1/

Thank  you to everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your `height` and `min-height` definitions so that `main` is told to be 100% high and *at least* 100vh:

```
main {
    /* height: 100vh; min-height: 100% !important; */ 
    height:100%; min-height: 100vh;
    ...
}
```

EG: https://jsfiddle.net/jqwqxL6n/3/

Comment: With `min-height: 100vh`, I don't think there's ever a need for `height: 100%`. I think `min-height: 100vh` is all that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Basically** you can use to your `#main: overflow-y: hidden;` It will solve your problem to hide the scroll bar but it'll also remove the option to scroll obviously. So, some text will be unreachable.
I'd suggest to make the area, where text is placed, bigger..

Comment: I want the text to be reachable but the scroll to be removed :) at most I want a read more button but once that is clicked I don't want scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `CSS` way on the main `div` and leave the height element

```
display:block;
overflow:auto;
```

Although you may not need but still for some browser to render the html, you can add this `position: relative`

Comment: Also try the link in [Tom Spee answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22682311/5588347).